# Is it possible to inject a Durandal widget after the page has been composed?

Tags: javascript, durandal

I am working on a durandal application and depending on certain action, I would need to inject a widget using `<!-- ko widget: {kind:'widget/cards'} --><!-- /ko -->`

At the moment the widget is not shown but only the comment can be seen in the HTML content.
Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Use the `if` or `visible` binding on the immediate parent node of your widget binding.  If there is no immediate parent node, create one solely for the purpose of holding the `if` or `visible` binding.

Take at this code from the DatePicker Widget I wrote *for* Durandal *with* Durandal (you can see the video [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=16C2A8798026D00B!173&authkey=!AIf5f0R_TXMvV0M&ithint=video%2Cmp4)):

```
<div>
    <div data-bind="visible: viewMode() === 'month'">
        <div data-bind="compose: {model: 'widgets/_common/datetime/datepickerMonth', view: 'widgets/_common/datetime/datepickerMonth', activate: true, activationData: messageChannel }"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible: viewMode() === 'months'">
        <div data-bind="compose: {model: 'widgets/_common/datetime/datepickerMonths', view: 'widgets/_common/datetime/datepickerMonths', activate: true, activationData: messageChannel }"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible: viewMode() === 'years'">
        <div data-bind="compose: {model: 'widgets/_common/datetime/datepickerYears', view: 'widgets/_common/datetime/datepickerYears', activate: true, activationData: messageChannel }"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Notice that I'm dynamically injecting which calendar view to show based on a condition**.  By the way, this is a bit of a trick for creating multi-view widgets (rather than having to write a custom view locator, which can get complicated).

**The principle is the same when you're dynamically injecting widgets** (as opposed to compositions, as I'm doing here).

I use the `visible` binding in this case for speed.  I don't want to recreate the compositions every time the user switches between views.  Users expect a datepicker to be more performant than that.

Comment: Sry for off topic but the calendar is simply awesome. Would be great if you could share the code

Comment: @zewa666  Thank you for the compliment.  I can't quite release all of the code yet--I'm working towards that.  I have written quite a few controls for Durandal using Durandal's technologies.  I will be releasing all of the controls as a suite (open source, of course).  Again, thank you!