# Durandal Child Routing issue

Tags: javascript, durandal

I am experiencing an issue with routing and composing in Durandal. My project structure and route configuration is pretty simple. My shell module contains a home route and a parent route (:id*splat). The parent routes module contains a child router with 4 routes configured.

The issue is when I navigate back to the **home page** from a **child route** and then back to the parent router (which has a default route i.e. ""), I see a flash of the previous child route and in the console a message stating Durandal is composing that child's route module, then Durandal jumps to the parents route default child route. This causes errors because the previous child route's modules compositionComplete function gets called, which contains selectors that are not truly there.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is it essential that your child routes be routed? Or is it your understanding that the only way to get to child views is by way of composed child routes?  I ask for a reason.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I'm not exactly sure what you mean. We choose to use a child router for our project, because the parent router (module which contains the child router) contains methods and data that are essential and common for all the child routes. For example: User selects something from the homepage, the parent router module gets data from server based on selection, and all the child routes get that data via the parent routers module and perform various manipulations on that data.

Comment: The reason I ask is that you can dynamically compose child views without the need to route to them.  You can pass data from the parent to the children by way of `activationData`.  Many folks are not aware that Durandal supports both navigational *and* compositional applications.  For example, in our enterprise app we have only top-level routes (no child routes), and yet we have hundreds of child views that dynamically swap in and out.

Comment: Where do you tell durandal what view to render base on activationData?

Comment: To answer your question: in your `compose` binding. Look at this fragment from our Datepicker (written entirely in Durandal), adapted for this discussion: `<div data-bind="compose: {model: theModel(), view: theView(), activate: true, activationData: activationParams}"`. Notice that `theView` and `theModel` are observables on the viewModel. When you change their values (strings pointing to your view/viewModel files), the compose binding will recompose and a new view will swap in.  Take a look at our Datepicker, referenced in the post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25924140/3174746.